# How i can get array from loop for?

Tags: javascript, loops

Hello everybody can you help me get percent with steps?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO2fn.png)

```js
function getPlan(currentProduction, months, percent) {
  // write code here
  let sum = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < months; i++){
    let workCalculate = currentProduction * percent / 100;

    sum *= workCalculate;
  }
  return Math.floor(sum);
}
```

example:
getPlan(1000, 6, 30) === [1300, 1690, 2197, 2856, 3712, 4825]
getPlan(500, 3, 50) === [750, 1125, 1687]

Comment: you're multiplying 0 with x , it will always be 0.

Comment: I know. But i can get it how i can return array with steps..

Comment: I cannot access the loop outside of it

Comment: Your image says you expect an _array_ with six integer as result, yet you do `return Math.floor(sum);` in your code - that does absolutely not fit together.

Comment: Decalre `let sumArray=[]` Then push elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply push each iteration to an array and return that array.

```js
function getPlan(currentProduction, months, percent) {
  // write code here
  // starting at currentProduction
  let sum = currentProduction;
 
  // output
  let output = [];
  
  for(let i = 0; i < months; i++){
    // progressive from sum and not from currentProduction
    let workCalculate = sum * percent / 100;
  
    sum += Math.floor(workCalculate);
    output.push(sum)
  };
  
  return output
};

console.log(getPlan(1000, 6, 30))
console.log(getPlan(500, 3, 50))
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your method returns a number, not an array. What do you need exactly? Do you need it to return an array or you just want to see the intermediate values of the calculation done inside the loop?

In the first case, create an empty array and add the values you want to it in each step of the loop:

```
function getPlan(currentProduction, months, percent) {
  // write code here
  let sum = 0;
  var result= [];

  for(let i = 0; i < months; i++){
    let workCalculate = currentProduction * percent / 100;
    sum *= workCalculate;
    result.push(sum);
  }

  return result;
}
```

In the second case, you have 2 options:

- Add a [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) so the values are printed to the console.
- Add a [breaking point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger-API/Tutorial-Breakpoint) so the code stops at it and you can see the values of the variables and go step by step through the execution of the program.

This is a bit vague because your need is unclear, hope it helps though!

Answer (score -1):

```js
function getPlan(currentProduction, months, percent) {
  var plan=[];
  var workCalculate=currentProduction;
  
  for(var i=0; i<months; i++) {
    workCalculate*=(1+percent/100);
    plan.push(Math.floor(workCalculate));
  }
  
  return plan;
}

console.log(getPlan(1000, 6, 30));
console.log(getPlan(500, 3, 50));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `floor()` seems to be at the wrong spot. Your actual output does not match your desired output on **4825**.

Comment: @Lain, thank you for your comment.
`floor` was in the question, I would have used `round`.
`4825` might be a mistake in the question, might be mine.

Comment: @Lain, ah - that's just copy-paste from the question that I didn't remove.  Removing...

Comment: `floor` where it is gives more accurate further results - especially if it was `round` instead.
With `round`: Say 10% on 100: 110, 121, 133(.1), 146(.31), **161** NOT 160 (160.941),
so I keep TRUE accumulator (`workCalculate`) and (would store the `round`, but here - ) store the `floor` of each iteration.
Down-Voter: Please justify.